# Issues Using NordVPN in Docker: TELIO Connection Errors

Tags: docker, networking, vpn

I am trying to use NordVPN within a Docker container but am encountering several errors during the connection process. These errors seem to involve issues with TELIO, specifically when attempting to use LinuxNativeWg and BoringTun adapters. Below are the error messages I'm receiving:

```
2024/02/27 09:22:07 [Error] TELIO: telio_start_named: Err(Adapter(LinuxNativeWg(Connect { source: NlError(Msg("uncategorized error")) })))
2024/02/27 09:22:08 [Error] TELIO: telio_start_named: Err(Adapter(BoringTun(IOCtl("Invalid argument"))))
2024/02/27 09:22:08 [Error] TELIO: telio_disconnect_from_exit_nodes: Err(NotStarted)
2024/02/27 09:22:08 [Error] TELIO: telio_disconnect_from_exit_nodes: Err(NotStarted)
2024/02/27 09:22:08 [Error] opening the tunnel: starting libtelio on retry with boring-tun: generic error
```

Despite extensive internet searches, I have been unable to find relevant information or solutions to these specific issues. I have tried several approaches to resolve the problem, including searching the internet for similar issues, setting net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, and trying different versions, but to no avail.

If anyone has experienced similar issues or has any insights on how to resolve these TELIO connection errors, particularly with the LinuxNativeWg connection and BoringTun adapter errors, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Methods attempted: Internet search, setting net.ipv4.ip_forward=1, trying different versions.

Thank you in advance for your help.